# how to get API to work?

Tags: android, json, api, twitter

After following a tutorial online I was able to retrieve some data from twitter for my android application. The following code works. I just basically want to build an application which can retrieve data such as Diablo 3 character level. How do I go about doing this? I think I have to use this URL to retrieve the data http://us.battle.net/api/d3/profile/Fauntleroy-1134/ however I am having no luck.

```
public class HttpExample extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;

final static String URL = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);   
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("created_at");
}

public JSONObject lastTweet(String username) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
        return last;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            json = lastTweet("");
            return json.getString(params[0]);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpStuff.setText(result);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: what's the problem, retrieving json string or parsing it?

Comment: In the LogCat in Eclipse I'm getting several System.err tags popping up, I can also see all of the information from the URL that I want to retrieve the data from. I figured that if I changed the value stored in 'final static String URL', and changed the string that is passed to the read() function the application would essentially continue to work. It would just be retrieving different information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data your are retrieving from [here](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=micheal) are stored in an Array, so when you parse the data with 
`JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);`

you will get your JSON**Array**.
 Every element of the **Array** is an **Object**, so you get it with
 `JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);`
 If you read the json string [here](http://us.battle.net/api/d3/profile/Fauntleroy-1134/) you'll notice that the string starts with "{", so the root element is not an Array but an Object.

You need to change your parsing code, try something like this:

```
// test json string
String data = "{\"heroes\" : [ {\"name\" : \"UUUGUUUUUUUU\",\"id\" : 92352,\"level\" : 60,\"hardcore\" : false,\"paragonLevel\" : 0,\"gender\" : 0,\"dead\" : false,\"class\" : \"demon-hunter\",\"last-updated\" : 1340492305}, {\"name\" : \"RhubarbVole\",\"id\" : 7531555,\"level\" : 50,\"hardcore\" : false,\"paragonLevel\" : 0,\"gender\" : 1,\"dead\" : false,\"class\" : \"monk\",\"last-updated\" : 1339377909}, {\"name\" : \"VoodooFrodo\",\"id\" : 7698952,\"level\" : 32,\"hardcore\" : false,\"paragonLevel\" : 0,\"gender\" : 0,\"dead\" : false,\"class\" : \"witch-doctor\",\"last-updated\" : 1339376344}, {\"name\" : \"CheeseBird\",\"id\" : 13139301,\"level\" : 7,\"hardcore\" : false,\"paragonLevel\" : 0,\"gender\" : 1,\"dead\" : false,\"class\" : \"wizard\",\"last-updated\" : 1338098485} ]}";

root = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray heroes = root.getJSONArray("heroes");

List<JSONObject> heroesList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

for(int i=0;i<heroes.length();i++){
    JSONObject hero = heroes.getJSONObject(i);          
    heroesList.add(hero);                   
}

//...

JSONObject hero = heroesList.get(x);
int level = hero.getInt("level");
```

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, I've attempted to change my code to this and the application still isn't doing what I'd expect it do, no doubt it'll be my wrongdoing as I'm not that great at coding.

Comment: I hope you will get it work but if have any doubts please feel free to ask.